# How can I remove unwanted lines from jboss logs?

Tags: logging, jboss

I made mistake and didn't remove debugging lines from code before it was deployed to production and some information that shouldn't be in logs is in jboss log files. How can I make java program to filter all unwanted lines by keword? Or is there any tool for this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss's logging is handled by log4j, and the log4j configuration file is `conf/jboss-log4j.xml`. Have a look at this, and if necessary read the log4j manual, it should hopefully be fairly self-explanatory. If you need more help, then give us some examples of the lines you want removed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how to remove certain lines from existing logs.

Here's what I use to remove DEBUG messages after enabling debugging in production for whatever reason:

```
perl -w -n -i -e 'print unless ( /DEBUG/../ERROR|WARN|INFO|FATAL/ && !/ERROR|WARN|INFO|FATAL/)' server.log.1
```

You can substitute whatever [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) matches just the lines you want to remove inside the parentheses above, for example:

```
perl -w -n -i -e 'print unless ( /SensitiveDebugInfo/ )' server.log.1
```

I'd be sure to only run this on logs that have been rolled over, to avoid potential file corruption from perl & jboss writing to the file simultaneously.